# Grunt connect-php not found, is it installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a problem when running my `grunt serve`. It says:

> Local Npm module "connect-php" not found. Is it installed?

All other grunt plugins I have been installing work just fine. And I can also see the plugin map for `connect-php` in my `node_modules` map as I'm supposed to.

Does anyone what the problem can be? Thanks.

Comment: Could you share your Gruntfile, or at least the parts that you might consider relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This part is added in the beginning of the Gruntfile.

```
var phpMiddleware = require('connect-php');
```

This part is added within the grunt.initConfig

```
connect: {
      options: {
        debug: true,
        livereload: true,
        port: 8000,
        base: '<%= config.destination %>',
      },
      rules: [
        {from: '(^((?!css|html|js|php|img|font|\/$).)*$)', to: '$1.html'},
      ],
      dev: {
        options: {
          middleware: function(connect, options) {
    var middlewares = [];
    var directory = options.directory || options.base[options.base.length -1];
    if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
        options.base = [options.base];
    }

    middlewares.push(phpMiddleware(directory));

    options.base.forEach(function(base) {
        // Serve static files. 
        middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
    });

    // Make directory browse-able. 
    middlewares.push(connect.directory(directory));
    return middlewares;
            }
        }
      }
    },
```

And i have this code in the end of the Gruntfile

```
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('connect-php');
```